# Return root from loop - Python

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, sqrt

I'm doing a class task and I'm stuck at returning root numbers from a loop separated by a comma. I can return one number but my loop seems to stop after that or something. I can't really find any clues on the mighty interweb but perhaps you can. The task is to return the root of i when i is between 5 and 20. So I thought of a while-loop but that might be a mistake.

```
import math

def multiplicator():
    """
    Return root from looped numbers
    """
    i = 5
    square = 0
    num = ""
    while i < 20:
        square = math.sqrt(i)
        num += str(square) + ","
        return num
        i += 1

ANSWER = multiplicator()
```

Could you please give me any pointers in this as I only get the root of the first number, 5.

Regards

Comment: You are returning from within the while loop. It will return in the very first iteration. Put it outside the while loop

Comment: Function returns only once. You could append a list of roots and then return it from function

Comment: You want to accumulate everything first, leave your loop *then* return. Your return is too early. When you have exhausted your while loop and it exits, your return should be outside that while.

Comment: Brilliant... This should stick some day. Have a nice evening.

Comment: On a sidenote, a more Pythonic way to do this: `','.join(map(str, map(math.sqrt, range(5, 20))))`. Or this: `','.join(str(math.sqrt(i)) for i in range(5, 20))`. By the way, you should never use string concatenation in a loop, because it is cery inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to move the return statement outside of the while loop, otherwise it'll stop the function as soon as you calculate the root of the first number.